# Extra <br/>s are appearing even when I remove them by looping and removeChild()

Tags: javascript, html

As the title states, I can't seem to find the suspect for this behaviour.

Here's my script:

```
function myFunction() {
        var marriedInputs = document.getElementById("marriedInputs");
        var status = document.getElementById("maritalStatusList").value;
        if (status == "Married") {
            var breaks = marriedInputs.getElementsByTagName("BR");
            for (var i = 0; i < breaks.length; i++) {
                    marriedInputs.removeChild(breaks[i]);
            }
            var spouseLabel = document.createElement("LABEL");
            spouseLabel.setAttribute("id", "spouseLabelID");
            spouseLabel.for = document.getElementById("spouseLname");
            var spouseLabelText = document.createTextNode("SPOUSE: ");
            spouseLabel.appendChild(spouseLabelText);

            var spouseLnameInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            spouseLnameInput.setAttribute("id","spouseLname");
            spouseLnameInput.setAttribute("type","text");
            spouseLnameInput.setAttribute("name","spouseLastName");
            spouseLnameInput.setAttribute("placeholder","Last Name");

            var spouseFnameInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            spouseFnameInput.setAttribute("id","spouseFname");
            spouseFnameInput.setAttribute("type","text");
            spouseLnameInput.setAttribute("name","spouseFirstName");
            spouseFnameInput.setAttribute("placeholder","First Name");

            var spouseMnameInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            spouseMnameInput.setAttribute("id","spouseMname");
            spouseMnameInput.setAttribute("type","text");
            spouseLnameInput.setAttribute("name","spouseMiddleName");
            spouseMnameInput.setAttribute("placeholder","Middle Name");

            var childrenNumInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            childrenNumInput.setAttribute("id","childrenNum");
            childrenNumInput.setAttribute("type","text");
            childrenNumInput.setAttribute("name","numOfChildren");
            childrenNumInput.setAttribute("placeholder","Number of Children");
            childrenNumInput.setAttribute("onkeypress","return isNumberKey(event)");

            var contactNumInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            contactNumInput.setAttribute("id","contactNum");
            contactNumInput.setAttribute("type","text");
            contactNumInput.setAttribute("name","spouseContactNo");
            contactNumInput.setAttribute("placeholder","Contact Number");
            contactNumInput.setAttribute("onkeypress","return isNumberKey(event)");

            var addressInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            addressInput.setAttribute("id","address");
            addressInput.setAttribute("type","text");
            addressInput.setAttribute("name","spouseAddress");
            addressInput.setAttribute("placeholder","Address");

            marriedInputs.appendChild(spouseLabel);
            marriedInputs.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
            marriedInputs.appendChild(spouseLnameInput);
            marriedInputs.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
            marriedInputs.appendChild(spouseFnameInput);
            marriedInputs.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
            marriedInputs.appendChild(spouseMnameInput);
            marriedInputs.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
            marriedInputs.appendChild(childrenNumInput);
            marriedInputs.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
            marriedInputs.appendChild(contactNumInput);
            marriedInputs.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
            marriedInputs.appendChild(addressInput);
            marriedInputs.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));

            document.getElementById("spouseLname").required = true;
            document.getElementById("spouseFname").required = true;
            document.getElementById("spouseMname").required = true;
            document.getElementById("childrenNum").required = true;
            document.getElementById("contactNum").required = true;
            document.getElementById("address").required = true;
        } else {
            if (document.body.contains(document.getElementById("spouseLname"))) {
                var breaks = marriedInputs.getElementsByTagName("BR");
                for (var i = 0; i < breaks.length; i++) {
                    marriedInputs.removeChild(breaks[i]);
                }
                marriedInputs.removeChild(document.getElementById("spouseLabelID"));
                marriedInputs.removeChild(document.getElementById("spouseLname"));
                marriedInputs.removeChild(document.getElementById("spouseFname"));
                marriedInputs.removeChild(document.getElementById("spouseMname"));
                marriedInputs.removeChild(document.getElementById("childrenNum"));
                marriedInputs.removeChild(document.getElementById("contactNum"));
                marriedInputs.removeChild(document.getElementById("address"));
            }
        }  
    }
```

Can anyone pinpoint the problem? I'm not really a js person, I just needed this for some onchange in a select element.

And I would very appreciate any tips for writing a cleaner version of this script. Cheers!!

Forgot the HTML:

```
Marital Status: 
<select id="maritalStatusList" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="Single">Single
    <option value="Married">Married
    <option value="Divorced">Divorced
    <option value="Widowed">Widowed
 </select>
 <div id="marriedInputs">

 </div>
```

Comment: @Rajesh Not really sure, I tried putting that to a variable, but it doesn't work, so I coded it directly to the appendChild. But based from the flow of the script, it should remove the BRs everytime the script is used whether the status married or the others. The problem is, there are still BRs appearing. Maximum of 2 br in married status, then 4 br for the others when I repeatedly change the select

Comment: @Rajesh The JSFiddle shows the same prob as mine, BRs appears above the spouse when I change the select multiple times

Comment: instead of adding `<br>`, you should wrap all inputs inside `<div>`. `div` being a block element, will start from new line. Also I'll check for issue

Comment: @Rajesh Guess I can use that. I have thought about that technique, but I would love if this problem will be solved for future concerns. Thanks for the response :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues in fetching `br`s and removing them. I tried replacing it with querySelector and it worked fine.

```js
function removeBRs() {
  var breaks = document.querySelectorAll('#marriedInputs br')
  for (var i = 0; i < breaks.length; i++) {
    marriedInputs.removeChild(breaks[i]);
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/f7v035uL/1/).

Also a side note, there is a lot of redundant code. Export them into smaller functions with common logic. Also, you can wrap all fields for `married` case inside a container `div` and append this div to main `#marriedInputs`. This will ease process of removing it.

Following is the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/f7v035uL/2/). I'd still recommend using `wrapper div` instead of `br` though. Also I have removed the use of `removeBRs` and deleted it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Like @Vsevolod's answer?.

Comment: @CarlJanBinalla I have updated my answer with slightly improved code. Major part is, you do not need `removeBRs` now. You can check as per your ease.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing this function in a different way:

```
function toggleMarriedInputs() {
   var status = document.getElementById("maritalStatusList").value;
   if (status == "Married") {
     var container = document.createElement("div");
     container.setAttribute("id", "marriedInputs");

     // creating inputs and appending them to #marriedInputs

     // appending #marriedInputs in target place
   } else {
       var marriedInputs = document.getElementById("marriedInputs");
       marriedInput.parentNode.removeChild(marriedInputs);
   }
```